# Insertion in string Python

Tags: python, string

I am learning to do some string manipulation python as you can see below trying to insert a character, but after some run it fails. Can you explain why ?

```
phone_num = str("+1-202-555--+0143+")


wrng = ['+','-']

for a in phone_num:    
    if a in wrng:
        b = phone_num.find(a)
        c = phone_num.rfind(a)
        if type(b)!= int or float:
            phone_num = phone_num[:b]+'0'+phone_num[b:]
            print(phone_num)
        elif type(c) != int or float:
            phone_num = phone_num[:c]+'0'+phone_num[c:]
        else:
            print("Wrong")
```

also trying to add the end but it fails.

```
0+1-202-555--+0143+
0+10-202-555--+0143+
0+100-202-555--+0143+
0+1000-202-555--+0143+
0+10000-202-555--+0143+
00+10000-202-555--+0143+
000+10000-202-555--+0143+
```

expecting was `0+1-202-555-0-0+0143+0`

Comment: Your `if`and `elseif` conditions are wrong, should be: `if type(a)!= int or type(a)!=float:`

Comment: `a` is a string.  `type(a)` is always going to be a `str`.  You can check if you have one of the characters 0-9, or you can try converting `a` to an int and see if you get an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Is the last `else ` statement meant to align with the `elif` or with the first `if`?

Comment: changing doesn't affect the output

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain what your code does and hope it'll help a bit with further steps.

It executes seven times since you have seven symbols, therefore you have 7 lines of output.

The first part of the first condition `type(a)!= int` always evaluates for true, since you only get there if a is either `+` or `-`. The `float` part of the boolean check will always evaluate to true, so you can delete it, there also will never be floats in a single character.

Whenever it is `+`, b will be the index of the leftmost + and the function will add a `0` in front of it. In the case it's a `-`, b will be the index of the leftmost `-` and add a `0` in front of that.

Comment: as under for loop the position should be updated and hoping to add 0.